# How do I solve this gate with constant voltage at both ends?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, logic-gates, grounding, memristor

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of the circuit in the work "Polynomial-time solution of prime factorization and NP-hard problems with digital memcomputing machines" for a project.
I'm not strong with circuit analysis so I'm having some problems understanding how to approach the problem.

[image: The circuit in question]

The M elements are memristors, basically resistors with memory. Before trying to understand the dynamics though, I wanted to get a gist of how the thing works at a specific time t.
Memristors have an internal variable x that varies from 0 to 1. The resistance of the memristors is:

[image: Memresistance]

where R_off is equal to R in the circuit scheme and R_on is a value that is lower than that. Other than this they behave exactly like resistors, so V = M I.

L_M are voltage-controlled voltage generators. Their equation is:

[image: Voltage-controlled voltage generators]

Where a_1, a_2, a_0 and d_c are all constant unitary values that comes from a table.
My question is: how do I even approach a circuit like this? If I undestood correctly, if v_1, v_2 and v_0 obey the configuration of an AND gate (such as -1, +1 and -1) there should be no current flowing. But given that both ends of the circuit have a constant voltage applied to them I can't see where should I start applying Kirchhoff's laws etc.

I tried starting from a configuration in which all the x values are 1 so that all memristors are just like normal resistors, but I still think I'm not doing things in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

There is current flow. Consider the picture on the RHS: the 5 branches are in parallel, driven by a given \$v_i\$ voltage (say, \$v_1\$). Then you can say the \$n-th\$ from the common node to ground will be:
$$i_n = \frac{v_i-L_{M_n}}{M(x)}$$
and the total current will be: \$i =\sum_{n=1}^4i_n+(v_i-L_R)/R\$. Hence you can see each branch will have a current depending on the value of the generator, whose values depend on the driving voltages and the constants you mentioned, and also on the value of the MR for a given \$x\$ value.

Then you can use MATLAB or Octave to see how it changes for various configurations. But the calculations are straightforward.